# Cannot change ViewportOut in Nvidia X Server Settings

Tags: nvidia, resolution

I have 2 monitors on Nvidia Card:

- First: 1440x900
- Second: 1280x1024

The first one works great. 
The second one has a resolution of 640x480. 
In Nvidia settings, I can choose only 640x480. 
If I change ViewportOut, it drops to 640x480.

It would be very cool if I could change resolution in `xorg.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can in `xorg.conf` but I am finding nvidia driver will not let me change it either there, too. Any help will do.

CLI: `:~$ nvidia-settings --verbose --assign CurrentMetaMode="DPY-3: 2560x1440 { ViewPortIn=2560x1440,ViewPortOut=2560x1440+0+0 }"`

**Xorg.conf:**

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "metamodes" "DPY-3: nvidia-auto-select 2560x1440 +0+0 {viewportout=2560x1440, viewportin=2560x1440}"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same resolutions and same problem. I have discovered that I have bad DVI-I-to-VGA adapter that cause undetecting monitor bios configuration.

1. I switched the adapters and connected only second monitor (1280x1024).
2. Logged in
3. Deleted previous /etc/X11/xorg.conf with backup on desktop
4. called nvidia-xconfig
5. Copied 2 sections: Monitor, Screen

```
   Section "Monitor"
        Identifier     "Monitor0"
        VendorName     "LG"
        ModelName      "LG FLATRON L1734S"
        HorizSync       63.0 - 67.0
        VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
        Option         "DPMS"
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "Screen0"
        Device         "Device0"
        Monitor        "Monitor0"
        DefaultDepth    24
        SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
            Modes      "1280x1024"
        EndSubSection
    EndSection
```

6. Shutdown pc
7. Replace adapters
8. Log in desktop environment
9. Open displays resolutions and choose the second monitor resolution

at least it works fine to me, but settings were reset after upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10